# Teradata TPT Error: EXPORT_OPERATOR: TPT10508: RDBMS error 9990: Response Row size exceeds 64K bytes and is incompatible with the Client software

Tags: export, teradata

I get this error when running tpt export. How to handle this in the script?
EXPORT_OPERATOR: TPT10508: RDBMS error 9990: Response Row size exceeds 64K bytes and is incompatible with the Client software.

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade to a newer version of TPT (e.g. 16.20) that supports larger rows, or change the SELECT statement in your EXPORT so that the max possible length for rows returned is under 64K bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Teradata query where several columns were clob data types. Since I only needed part of those fields I just extracted the relevant strings using `regexp_substr()` and cast the result to varchar:

```
SELECT cast (regexp_substr (foo, '[0-9]+[A-Z]+') as varchar(10)) AS res
FROM sometable
(...)
```